# BigBlueButton on DigitlOcean Droplet in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, bigbluebutton

I run BigBlueButton on a digitalocean droplet. The BBB was installed as a docker (using instructions here https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html)And the storage space became full after several sessions. Therefore I have purchased block storage and attached to the droplet using automatic format and attach option. Do I have to do anything else to tell BBB to use this extra space or will it take and consume automatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue by creating simlink. I understand DigitalOcean adds volume as  directory therefore BBB should be simlinked to that directory to store recordings.
I followed these comments:

```
  sudo mv /var/bigbluebutton /var/bigbluebutton.backup #to move the existing ones to backup
  sudo ln -s /mnt/sdb /var/bigbluebutton  # create simlink
  sudo bbb-conf --restart #restrart
```

This will help to increase storage without interruption to old recordings.
Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Is there any missing step here? The presentation stops appearing after these steps.